# Imported an FBX model, why does it look different in the 3D Viewport and in render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, visibility

I downloaded an FBX file from [here](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/kizuna-ai-c9eb5d213fe54a96a4b3b77a7b509920) (Needs a free account to download the file). In the ZIP file, it had two directories: "source" and "textures". After some trial and error, I have found that I must place all the files in the same directory to make Blender to import the model correctly.

So, now I have imported the FBX model, and it looks correctly in the Viewport like the first image below. But when I render the model, it looks like the second image below. Why is that? I have tried changing the visibilities of various parts (by clicking the eye icons), but none of them worked.

What should I do to make the render look like the Viewport? If you need to see my Blender project file to answer the question, please tell me so; I will upload the file and share the link. It is just that last time I asked a question here, I shared the link to my Blender project file, none of those who answered seemed to have downloaded the file, so this time I am not uploading the file as of now.

[image]
[image]

---

PS: After following the comment, I could it now looks like these below. I tried disable everything I could think of, but the log-like things did not go away in render.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you hide something in the viewport (with the eye icon in the outliner) it won't be hidden in the render automatically. To hide them in render click on the funnel icon on the top of the outliner and enable the render visibility (camera icon). Then you can hide the unwanted object from render in the outliner.

Comment: @FFeller I clicked the funnel and clicked "Disable in Renders". Now camera icons appear right to the eye icons, but I cannot find out what those translucent thick log-like things are. If I disable the camera icon in the "mesh" line, the character was gone in the render, but those logs still remain. Could you tell me what item I should disable to hide those logs? I will append screen captures for these.

Comment: Those are inside of the rigidbodies empty.

Comment: @FFeller Thanks. It is solved.